# Unable to use DEFAULT SESSION_USER in table constraint (switches to user_name instead)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have defined a constraint with a default value of `SESSION_USER`, eg as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [test] (col1 varchar(50))
GO
ALTER TABLE [test]  ADD  CONSTRAINT [x]  DEFAULT SESSION_USER FOR [col1]
GO
```

This seems to run fine - `Command(s) completed successfully.`

However - the actual definition has been modified to use the `user_name()` function, eg as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[test] ADD  CONSTRAINT [x]  DEFAULT (user_name()) FOR [col1]
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `SESSION_USER` is a synonym for `USER_NAME()`:

> When you are connected to an instance of SQL Server, use the following
>   to obtain user name or user IDs:
>
> ...
>
> - Either the ISO `CURRENT_USER` or `SESSION_USER` functions to obtain the database user name associated with the current connection. In
>     Transact-SQL, these functions are implemented as synonyms for
>     `USER_NAME()`. (`USER_NAME` specified without a `database_user_ID`
>     parameter.) The Transact-SQL function `USER` is also implemented as a
>     synonym for `USER_NAME()`.

(Source: [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms191126)).

Constraints are reduced to a normal form on compilation rather than being stored as-is like stored procedures are. You'll notice that extra parenthesis have been added as well. While the literal definition is not retained, the semantics are.